# Highcharts JS setData in spline

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a chart I want to update when a user updates something in his/her profile. The data structure is like this:

```
var chartData = "[date1,weight1],[date2,weight2],[date3,weight3]";
```

I create the string in JS before sending the string to setData. However I cant get the update to work:

```
chart.series[0].setData([chartData]);
chart.redraw();
```

What I want to do is update the axis with the dates and plot the weight for the user. I am sure I am doing it wrong, but I cant figure out, what I am doing wrong - I am sure you know the feeling :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
var chartData = [];

// push two items to chart
chartData.push({ name: "my item #1 title", y : 100 });
chartData.push({ name: "my item #2 title", y : 200 });

// update chart data
chart.series[0].setData(chartData);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
chart.series[0].setData([chartData], true);
```